# Post form data in route in node js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

When I post form data to routing then, getting a undefined parameter error. I can't to send the form parameter to routing file. Please help me. Here is my code with files name

**Getting Error**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

**node.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.route('/').get(function(req,res) {      
    fs.readFile('./html/registers.html',function(err,data) {    
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content_type':'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
});    

app.post('/formData', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    console.log("post received: %s %s", username, password);
});
```

**register.js**

```
<form action="formData" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" name="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did u have `app.use(bodyParser.json())` this line in server code??

Comment: When i add   "app.use(bodyParser.json()); "  then form can't to post data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace the following

```
<form action="formData" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

By

```
<form action="/formData" method="post">
```

Before the route function add following

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: After add your code ,I'm  getting error "post received: undefined undefined
".

Comment: Please remove the enctype and check